# Laravel | is it possible to specify 2 different domain in one laravel project

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have one weird requirement from the client to access the website from 2 different domains but it should be the same code base and the same database so is there any way in .env file I can specify both domains?

For example
abc.com, xyz.com should point to the same laravel project with the same database & code base.

Comment: you can able to mention the dynamic APP URL in Appserviceprovide. Even if you want to load a different .env file for each domain. that is also achievable.

Comment: so both URLs will work at the same time? @KmgKumar

Answer (score 0):

If it's really the same site for both, why not just put in a permanent redirect for `xyz.com` pointing to `abc.com`?  Unless you want the same site for both serving the same content except on another domain.  Then you can accomplish this through a dynamic middleware on your routes. This will let you know what domain is accessing the route and you can change out headers, logos, linking..etc  You can also treat this as a multi-tenant situation also having the same base Laravel database and using another database for each of the domains to offer up different content and different blade templating. The first step is pointing both domains to your public folder on your server.